# Mysql select minutes from future date time - now()

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my database which holds an expire time being inserted with NOW() + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;

I need to be able to pull out minutes remaining from that column. I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `that time - NOW()` converted to minutes

Comment: @Rogue thanks that worked. I wasn't sure you could just throw that in a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),column1) AS minutes_remaining FROM table1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Note that the order of the arguments is extremely counterintuitive... to get a positive number as a result, the larger (later) datetime value is the last argument.  If the second argument is >= the third, the result will be <= 0.